Nextjs 14 dark screen chunks error coming in production
I am having this error on my Nextjs 14 application. It comes anytime on the site and goes away after hard refresh.There is no error in consoleenter image description here
I tried disabling cache but still the issue arises its mainly comes when the network is slow or the app is closed and when we try to open it again
